# scraping Xbox Live member current activity

Tags: php, screen-scraping, xbox

I'm looking into how to get a Xbox Live member's presence (i.e. Not Online, Online playing *_*).

The only way is to be signed into Xbox.com, visit the player's page, and scrape some text from a div.  http://live.xbox.com:80/en-US/MyXbox/Profile?gamertag=example Seen here

```
<div id="CurrentActivity">
     Call of Duty Black Ops - In Combat Training on Summit
</div>
```

Is there a way to sign into http://xbox.com with a script or otherwise find a player's current status?

**EDIT:**
Here is my project [Xbox Messenger / Status](http://halogamertags.com/xbox.check/)

Comment: Check if XBOX has an API, you can usually get the data that way!

Comment: XBOX does have an API but it's flippin hard to get access to it and the API does not give him the data he's looking for; it doesn't even give you your achievements :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cab use `curl` in PHP.  You will need to store the cookies and reuse your cookie file with subsequent requests.

Another scripting option is to use `mechanize`. There isn't a PHP library last I checked, but there is one for Python, perl and Ruby.

Comment: This does not work, you must use a method that can utilize JS as MS' login forms requires it. You can steal your RPSAuth cookie from your browser and use that but that's just a dirty session hijack method that'll only keep you logged in for up to 12 hours after which you need a new cookie.

Answer (score 2):

http://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?Gamertag=GAMERTAG

here u can find the players Xbox Live online Status without being logged in to the site. Scrape it with any method you find over the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can record a robot using IRobotSoft web scraper if you just need an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is code that i just made this will work

```
$opentag='<div class="presence">';
$closetag='</div>';
$url=file_get_contents('http://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?gamertag=major%20nelson')


$presence=explode($opentag, $url);
$presence=explode($closetag, $presence[1]);

echo trim($presence[0]);
```